# Google Android Gcm Server

Tags: android

I can't get to use the

> import com.google.android.gcm.server.Message;
>
> import com.google.android.gcm.server.Result;
>
> import com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender;

the three Libraries are not working for me, please how did you get it to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downlaod gcm.jar and add it on build path

Right click on project in build path->configure build path select java build path
and then select Library tab and add jar clicking Add external jars option and select gcm.jar

Comment: Okay, I've been looking for build path too, I saw one and tried to add Jar to it, but I can't

Comment: Don't worry, I added it to my Lib directory and forgot to add it to my build path...Thank You anyway

Comment: okay, already did. Add this comment for me, I don't have enough reputation to answer my questions "Add gcm.jar to Lib directory and then right click on it, then highlight BuildPath> then select add to build path...and Voila that's all"